# why different result between max(list,key) and max(set(list), key) in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, max

I am learning the CS212 in Udacity and have the following code.

---

User Instructions:
Write a function best_wild_hand(hand) that takes as
input a 7-card hand and returns the best 5 card hand.
In this problem, it is possible for a hand to include
jokers. Jokers will be treated as 'wild cards' which
can take any rank or suit of the same color. The 
black joker, '?B', can be used as any spade or club
and the red joker, '?R', can be used as any heart 
or diamond.

---

here is the code:

```
import itertools

def best_wild_hand(hand):
    "Try all values for jokers in all 5-card selections."


    if '?B' not in hand and '?R' not in hand:
        return max(itertools.combinations(hand,5), key=hand_rank)


    black = [ i+j for i in list('23456789TJQKA') for j in ['S','C']]
    red = [ i+j for i in list('23456789TJQKA') for j in ['H','D']]

    cards = []
    hands = []


    if '?B' in hand and '?R' not in hand:
        for item in black:
            temp = hand[:]
            temp[temp.index('?B')] = item
            cards.append(temp) 
    elif '?R' in hand and '?B' not in hand:
        for item in red:
            temp = hand[:]
            temp[temp.index('?R')] = item
            cards.append(temp)
    else:
        for i in black:
            for j in red:
                temp = hand[:]
                temp[temp.index('?B')] = i
                temp[temp.index('?R')] = j
                cards.append(temp)
    #cards = set(cards)

    for card in cards:
        hands  += itertools.combinations(card, 5)

    #print(len(hands))
    #hands = set(hands)
    #print(len(hands))
    return max(hands, key=hand_rank)


def test_best_wild_hand():
    assert (sorted(best_wild_hand("6C 7C 8C 9C TC 5C ?B".split()))
            == ['7C', '8C', '9C', 'JC', 'TC'])
    assert (sorted(best_wild_hand("TD TC 5H 5C 7C ?R ?B".split()))
            == ['7C', 'TC', 'TD', 'TH', 'TS'])
    assert (sorted(best_wild_hand("JD TC TH 7C 7D 7S 7H".split()))
            == ['7C', '7D', '7H', '7S', 'JD'])
    return 'test_best_wild_hand passes'

# ------------------
# Provided Functions
# 
# You may want to use some of the functions which
# you have already defined in the unit to write 
# your best_hand function.

def hand_rank(hand):
    "Return a value indicating the ranking of a hand."
    ranks = card_ranks(hand) 
    if straight(ranks) and flush(hand):
        return (8, max(ranks))
    elif kind(4, ranks):
        return (7, kind(4, ranks), kind(1, ranks))
    elif kind(3, ranks) and kind(2, ranks):
        return (6, kind(3, ranks), kind(2, ranks))
    elif flush(hand):
        return (5, ranks)
    elif straight(ranks):
        return (4, max(ranks))
    elif kind(3, ranks):
        return (3, kind(3, ranks), ranks)
    elif two_pair(ranks):
        return (2, two_pair(ranks), ranks)
    elif kind(2, ranks):
        return (1, kind(2, ranks), ranks)
    else:
        return (0, ranks)

def card_ranks(hand):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r) for r, s in hand]
    ranks.sort(reverse = True)
    return [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] if (ranks == [14, 5, 4, 3, 2]) else ranks

def flush(hand):
    "Return True if all the cards have the same suit."
    suits = [s for r,s in hand]
    return len(set(suits)) == 1

def straight(ranks):
    """Return True if the ordered 
    ranks form a 5-card straight."""
    return (max(ranks)-min(ranks) == 4) and len(set(ranks)) == 5

def kind(n, ranks):
    """Return the first rank that this hand has 
    exactly n-of-a-kind of. Return None if there 
    is no n-of-a-kind in the hand."""
    for r in ranks:
        if ranks.count(r) == n: return r
    return None

def two_pair(ranks):
    """If there are two pair here, return the two 
    ranks of the two pairs, else None."""
    pair = kind(2, ranks)
    lowpair = kind(2, list(reversed(ranks)))
    if pair and lowpair != pair:
        return (pair, lowpair)
    else:
        return None 


print(test_best_wild_hand())
```

---

Above code just works fine. However, when I change the last line in def best_wild_hand(hand) as

```
 return max(set(hands), key=hand_rank)
```

The result is wrong. Why I conver the `list` to `set` and the `max()` does not work? Thanks

Comment: ok first there's no need to use set() if you want to find the maximum in a list, secondly, we need to  know what is inside the list "hands" (is it a list of tuples ? a list of dictionnaries ?) or else it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Inspi, I covert to  `set` since `hands` may have the repeat elements. Also the `hands` is a list of tuple like: `[('6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC'), ('6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', '5C')]`. thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure using set() will be slower than keeping the list as is, even with duplicates, also are you sure the function hand_rank works like you intend to ?

Comment: @Inspi, yes, the `hand_rank` is provided by the udacity. I am quite suprising that convert `list` to `map`, the `max()` does not work.

Comment: you should also check that hands is filled with the hands you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

### The lack of ordering in set makes the return of `max(set(hands))` unstable, sometimes returning wrong answer, sometimes correct.

After a lot of digging, I think I have found the source of the bug. To begin with, your logic was correct: by calling set(), you removed duplicates, so the result should be the same with or without duplicates.

In the original code, if the second test case is commented out, using `set(hands)` would pass the other cases (at least in my environment). Thus, the problem might be with the second test case.

If you isolate the second test case out, and run the program with `set(hands)` for, say 20 times, the tricky thing happens: most of the time the test case fails, but in a few times it actually passes!

This is crazy! The same code gives different results. The correct output for the second test case is `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TH', 'TS')`. But the max function would also return at least two other outputs `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TH', 'TC')` and `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TD', 'TS')`.

If you inspect the return value of `hand_rank()` when called on all these three hands, the results are the same `(7, 10, 7)`. In other words, these three hands are identical in their ranking. Thus, which one to return as max depends on whether it is a list or set that is passed to a max function.

If a list is passed, as in the case of `hands`, the first occurrence of the biggest value is returned. In this case, the index of `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TH', 'TS')` is 9081, index of `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TH', 'TC')` is 9627, and index of `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TD', 'TS')` is 9102. Therefore, when `hands` is passed, the correct answer `('TD', 'TC', '7C', 'TH', 'TS')` is always returned.

If a set is passed, since there is no internal ordering, the returned value could vary, which is exactly the behavior we have observed. For further testing, you can try this:

```
max([(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'c')],key=lambda x:x[0]) # output (2, 'a')
max({(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'c')},key=lambda x:x[0]) # output (2, 'c') or any of the other two depending on implementation
```

In conclusion, the cause of failed test when `set(hands)` is passed is the implementation-dependent behavior of calling max on set when multiple elements have the same ranking. But to push this issue further, it might be pure luck that the correct answer is returned with `hands`, because if during the combination step the wrong answer gets appended ahead of the correct answer, the wrong one would have been returned by max function. I would say the test case should be modified to include all these three hands as potential correct answer.